# Explicit Resolution of Singularity

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry

Has someone ever done/seen the explicit computation of the minimal resolution $Y$ of $X=\mathbb{C}^2/\mathbb{Z}/n= \text{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^n)?$ what is the best description of $Y$ if one doesn't what to do (if it's possible) the annoying computation?

Certainly, I can write explicitly all the equations in various charts of $Y,$ for $n=2,3,4,$ but I think, it's almost impossible to come up with formulas in general for $n.$ I guess the answer for my second question will be working with fans and toric varieties, if that's so, then what're the relations between various charts.

Comment: Best is to use toric geometry, I can make an answer later if you are interested.

Comment: @rain I did the general case on my [thesis](https://open.library.ubc.ca/cIRcle/collections/ubctheses/24/items/1.0074268) when I was in math!

Comment: omg I was gonna study this next semester !

Answer (score 4):

The morphism $Y\to X$ is an isomorphism aways from the unique singular point $x=y=z=0$ of $X$ (if $n\ge 2$, otherwise $X$ is smooth).

Let $R$ be the discrete valuation ring $\mathbb C[z]_{z\mathbb C[z]}$ with uniformizer $z$. Then 
The local ring of $X$ at the singular point is also the localization of $R[x,y]/(xy-z^n)$ at the maximal ideal generated by $x,y,z$. This singularity is a so called ordinary double point.

The minimal resolution of singularity in this case is well known. The exceptional locus (the pre-image of the singular point) consists in a chain of $n-1$ projective lines. The extremal lines cut the strict transfrom of the line $x=0$ (resp. $y=0$) with parameter $y$ (resp. $x$) at $y=0$ (resp. $x=0$).

In general it is not necessary to know each chart in the desingularization.

Comment: Dear @QiL, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The explicit computation is not so hard.  Deal with $n=2$ and $n=3$ explicitly, and then inductively relate the $n$ case to the $n-2$ case.

Comment: Dear Rhys, that's not possible in the classical sense of blowing up the singularities.

Comment: I don't understand - do you mean it's not the approach you want?  Because it's certainly possible; I've done it myself!

Comment: Yes, literally impossible. If you have resolved the cases for n=2,3,4,5 you will see that the number of blow ups needed is 1,1,2,4,... In fact it is easy to find the number blowups to resolve the case n in terms of the number of blowups of previous cases. Anyway, I have found a better way, which I'd write it as the answer when I find enough time.

Comment: Yes, what you say is correct (except it's $1,1,2,2,3,3,...$), but that's why you do it inductively.  If you do the first blow-up of an $A_n$ singularity, you find two smooth patches, and one patch with an $A_{n-2}$ singularity.  The global structure is two rational curves intersecting at precisely the singular point.

Comment: Yes, the number of blowups you gave is correct. If you're familiar with toric geometry, it's easy to write down everything in terms of lattice points of the resolved fan and this is more subtle than just blowing up numerous times.

Comment: Fair enough, the toric approach is nice.  Like I say, it depends what you want.

Comment: Dear @Rhys, yes, indeed. Btw thanks for your comments :)